# Tic-tac-toe game. ends whenever the last row is filled?

Tags: c, tic-tac-toe

This is a tic-tac-toe game. The problem is if the last row is filled, the game prints "Draw" and ends, This is supposed to happen only if all the cells are filled. What's my fault?!

http://pastebin.com/RZZn5wWe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The break statement terminates the execution of the nearest enclosing
>   `do`, `for`, `switch`, or `while` statement in which it appears. Control
>   passes to the statement that follows the terminated statement.

When you set your empty_cell variable you use a break in a nested loop. Doing this you exit only from the first loop and continue in the second. this is causing your issue.

Set your flag out of the loop and change it only if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing out the issue and a solution. Another way to solve it by using a goto statement.